Automatic scroll on jupyterlab 4
I've switched to Jupyterlab 4, but I'm noticing some pretty annoying behavior at times. When I launch a cell that gives me a rather long output, jupyter automatically scrolls to the end of the output, even though I don't want it to scroll. How can I disable this behavior?
I use Chrome on MacOS.
Edit : I run cell via Shift + Enter

Have you tried using CTRL + Enter or Command + Enter instead? For more context: see here for more context. Plus, on my machine when I look at the 'Run' menu in JupyterLab Version 4.2.0rc0, I see it listing different options with Shift, Ctrl, or Command combinations.  Or maybe what you are seeing is related to this issue with JupyterLab 4.2. The details there and at links therein may help you sort this better or ...

 see how to describe / share your issue better, citing specific versions, etc..
